# Elasticsearch date format

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, timestamp, datetime-format

I'm trying to send the following JSON input to elasticsearch but I'm obtaining a parser error.

This the JSON input

```
{
    "chassisNumber": "654321",
    "position": "40.480143, -3.688960",
    "issue": "Position",
    "timestamp": "2016-07-15T15:29:50+02:00[Europe/Paris]"
}
```

the Index definition

```
{
   "mappings":{
      "vehicle":{
         "properties":{
            "vehicle":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "position":{
               "type": "geo_point"
            },
            "issue":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "timestamp":{
               "type":"date",
               "format":"YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And the error associated with the "timestamp" field.

```
"reason": "Invalid format: \"2016-07-15T15:29:50+02:00[Europe/Paris]\" is malformed at \"[Europe/Paris]\""
```

I tried with a few date formats but no one was success. Can anybody help me to define the correct format to parse the "timestamp" field in elasticsearch?

Thanks!!!

Comment: You need to remove the `[Europe/Paris]` part, it's not needed as `+02:00` is sufficient.

Answer (score 29):

As you can see in the mapping that your field `timestamp` is mapped as `date` type with format `YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ssZ`. So, Elasticsearch would want the `timestamp` field to be passed in same format. The data you are passing is `2016-07-15T15:29:50+02:00[Europe/Paris]` which includes `[Europe/Paris]` after zone data which is not given in mapping and does not follow default `ISO 8601` format supported by Elasticsearch (more data available [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/mapping.html#mapping-date)).

You can read more on default date format supported by Elasticsearch [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/mapping-date-format.html#built-in-date-formats).

So either you have to remove extra data passed to Elasticsearch and keep it according to mapping

```
{
    "chassisNumber": "654321",
    "position": "40.480143, -3.688960",
    "issue": "Position",
    "timestamp": "2016-07-15T15:29:50+02:00"
}
```

or change your mapping to custom date format which follows the joda syntax defined [here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html). In your case if it is literal zone required you have to use `z` too.